# Expo to React Native Cli

Tags: javascript, react-native, npm, expo, react-native-cli

I am trying to run an android emulator in Android Studio for react native cli, I successfully ejected from Expo app to react native but when i tried to run android emulator I got this Error
"CommandError: The development client (com.project.myapp002) for this project is not installed"
Please what is the Error, and How can I fix it. thanks

Comment: Do you have Android Studio installed?

Comment: Yes, I have android studio installed